# How to implement LIKE condition in postgresql version 12?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, postgresql-12

```
Select COUNT(*) from Table_one where timestamp LIKE '%2020-03-04%' AND speed_type = 'SPEED';
```

This query is showing error when I am implementing it via spring boot framework so I checked it out on postgresql and still it's showing error.

The error is this:-

```
 ERROR:  operator does not exist: date ~~ unknown
LINE 1: Select COUNT(*) from table_one where timestamp LIKE '2020-0...
                                                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 49
```

Comment: How is `timestamp LIKE '%2020-03-04%'` different from `timestamp = '2020-03-04'` if `timestamp` is a date?

Comment: comparing timestamp or dates with LIKE is a really, really bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast your `timestamp` column as `VARCHAR` to allow it to be compared to a character string:

```
Select COUNT(*) 
from Table_one 
where CAST(timestamp AS VARCHAR) LIKE '%2020-03-04%'
  AND speed_type = 'SPEED';
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=827e7f52e51e2b4b428c35e21624f64a)

Comment: Ok I am trying to do it with spring also

Answer (score 2):

Use date/time functions!  Don't convert to a string!

```
where timestamp >= '2020-03-04' AND
      timestamp < '2020-03-05' AND
      speed_type = 'SPEED'
```

Not only does this prevent unnecessary type conversion.  But it is also immune to any internationalization settings that might affect conversion to a string (that might depend on the database).

It can also use appropriate indexes that include `timestamp`.  And the optimizer has better information, which can improve the query plan (although the plan in this case is, admittedly, simple).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're comparing a timestamp value with a string type value. So, a conversion needed such as

```
timestamp::text LIKE '%2020-03-04%'
```

Comment: I need to use this query in spring